# How Do You Manage Religion in World Building?

Tags: science-fiction, religion, writing

I may be asking this in the wrong place, as it could be a pretty subjective question- just let me know and I’ll ask elsewhere, but I saw on a recent post that the Code of Conduct on this site prohibits religious slander, etc, which got me thinking about my own story. I’m not particularly religious or offended by religious criticism, but the world I’m building does have a (albeit heavily exaggerated) religious extremist group/death cult based on Christianity. Is this generally a thing to avoid? Is it better to invent some new hypothetical religion for a story? What are people’s opinions on this? I don’t want to offend people with my story, but the Christianity thing is kind of important for some of the imagery and inspiration for my (mostly sci-fi) story. I can provide specific examples if necessary, but I figured this would be a good general question for using religions that are still in practice for antagonists. Are there any ways to easily illustrate that a religious group depicted in a story does not reflect the actual portrayal of the religion?

Comment: You might indeed be better on the Writing stack, and it would still be somewhat opinion based. I think you're gonna need a move and a rewriting of the question to fit the StackExchange format so that your question can be properly answered. Not against you, but VTC-ing for the reasons above.

Comment: This looks more like a question for writing.SE. And SE's code of conduct does not apply to your own story, only to what you post here

Comment: It looks like you're wanting to have a discussion where people share their opinions rather than ask a specific answerable question. Such questions aren't a good fit for any SE site. As a rule asking "What do you do?" or "What are peoples opinions on X?" are blatantly out of scope for a SE site.

Comment: @Nyakouai Will do. Thanks!

Comment: @sphennings Ok. Any idea where I should ask it?

Comment: I don't know. If you go to writing.SE you should read their help center to understand their site specific rules. It's possible you could revise your question so that you're asking something more specific.

Comment: @sphennings I’ll do my best. Thanks. Not sure how to close this question but thanks all for the help!

Comment: @MarkPrice, you can simply delete it

Comment: Are you asking about the practicalities of writing and selling your work? Then this is the wrong place.  We try to answer questions about how to build your death cult, and how it interacts with the rest of the world. (But as a practical matter, any story that involves religion is going to offend someone.  Just remember that there are a lot of non-Christians you can sell to, if your story's good enough.  OTOH, there's a whole sub-genre of Christian science fiction.)

Comment: ??? Philip Pullman's [*His Dark Materials*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/His_Dark_Materials) trilogy is obviously centered around an exaggerated (and *very* thinly disguised) version of the Universal Church, who, spoler alert, are the baddies, as is the object of their devotion. At the other end of the spectrum,  C. S. Lewis's [*Narnia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Chronicles_of_Narnia) series is equally obviously Christian apologetics disguised as fantasy. Both were very successful.

Comment: I read this as a process of worldbuilding question. Mark, I think if you edited out the bits where you're asking for discussion or opinions, you'll get more dispassionate / fact or practice based answers.

Comment: Mark, just so you're aware: 1) there's no reason for you to delete this question -- it's a fair question about the process of worldbuilding and is thus on topic here; 2) you can't delete a question by blanking what you wrote -- I'll just come along behind you and restore what you changed; 3) even if you wanted to delete it, now that it has answers you can't; 4) lastly, all you need to do here is edit your question to remove the bits where you're asking for discussion and opinion! Again, your underlying question is 100% on topic and has a limited number of reasonable answers.

Comment: OP indicated that they crossposted it here. https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/59363/is-having-antagonists-who-believe-in-christianity-potentially-offensive-harmful

Comment: @DanielB -- I think the query in Writing is of sufficiently different character that it's a new (non-duplicate) question. Thanks for pointing us to it!

Comment: @DanielB -- I rolled back to Mark's original wording because that's the question I answered. I *really do like* your version of the question, and I'd encourage you to ask that as a separate query, rather than alter this one!

Answer (score 3):

### Tread Carefully but Boldly!

Although this is not a discussion forum, there are a few rules / strong guidelines that ought to be taken into consideration when worldbuilding and considering a fictional religion.

1. You ***SHALL*** offend somebody. Just getting that out of the way. In modern occidental culture, you can hardly put two words together in a public place without ticking off some group of people. Be aware of this, and don't let their offense get to you personally. (If your goal is, in fact, to offend people, then job well done!)
2. Basing a religious extremist group/death cult on Christianity is nothing new in fiction. We're used to it in real life, and the situation in fiction isn't much better. As with borrowing from or basing your invented cultures on any real group of people, be aware of "appropriation". Don't name or copy specifics (e.g. the Eucharist or a particular saint) and twist them or write slanderously about them. If you want to borrow general forms or practices, like governing bodies or geographical divisions or generic things like hierarchical or architectural structures, feel free! If you want to be inspired or informed by imagery or cultural penetration, those are also fair game.
3. It is always better to invent rather than to copy. Much will depend on what you actually mean by "based on Christianity". Without knowing your situation, most "not particularly religious" people really don't know anything about Christianity (or any other religion). This can either be good, because you're less likely to actually write anything offensive; or it can be bad if you end up creating a slavish and stupid copy of a religion.
4. Do a little homework! Find an introduction to world religions (something like Religion for Dummies), just so that you'll deepen your understanding of what religion means and how it works in people's lives from a number of different perspectives.
5. Always err on the side of respect. Try to avoid using well known terms, titles or names in a bad way. E.g., in stead of calling the leader "the Pope", choose a different title that gets the idea across like "Hierarch" or "Covenant Maker".
6. Write well to be understood well. Once you know your stuff, the best thing you can do to prevent offense or ill will is to write your material well. The better picture you have in your mind of this fictional religion, the more clearly we'll see it and understand that what you're making is not intended as an insult.
7. Read how others before you have done it! My go-to example is to read Terry Pratchett's Discworld novel *[Small Gods](https://discworld.fandom.com/wiki/Great_God_Om#Small_Gods)* and read about the [Omnian religion](https://discworld.fandom.com/wiki/Omnia). It's clearly a parody of Christianity, but is also more than enough of its own entity that no intelligent person will mistake it for Christianity.
8. And this will be your toughest task, and the most important rule, is to **make this religion its own thing**.

Comment: Re #7, I like to think of myself as an intelligent person, yet I certainly saw the Omnian religion as a (perhaps somewhat hyperbolic) reflection of Christianity.  Perhaps only Christians would see it as parody, some others would see it as laying bare the reality :-(

Comment: @jamesqf -- That's an understandable perspective. The question becomes: *which reality* is he laying bare? If we're talking sex scandals, money scandals, power grabbing, mismanagement, prelate corruption & abuse of power or authority, then yeah, I'd say PTerry was spot on. The Catholic church as an organisation has suffered all of those things. It becomes obvious, then, that this isn't really a statement about the church so much as it is commentary on any organisation in which humans are involved. He just chose the church as a convenient target. If we're talking about all the stuff that ...

Comment: (cont) ... doesn't get talked about like feeding the hungry, healing the sick, comforting the  hurting, attending to the poor, dignifying labour, raising the status of women & children and people who aren't rich & landed & titled, uplifting the human condition in general, foundation of hospitals, universities, patronising arts & sciences, etc then I'd say PTerry was out of depth by many cable lengths. So yeah: I can easy agree that Omnianism is a reflection of the worst the church has revealed about human nature while utterly ignoring what Catholicism is actually all about.

Comment: We would certainly disagree about what Christianity in general (not just the Catholic Church) is about, but the moderators probably wouldn't let us discuss it.

Answer (score 2):

As a highly religious person myself, I would rather you write honestly and humbly than anything else. Ie. I would want you to portray what you think the real religions your representing are like, and be humble enough to recognize you are probably very wrong. The things I wrote about Catholicism when I was Protestant can easily earn a massive facepalm from me now that I am Catholic. It is rare for anyone, on my experience, to know any religion in detail except the one they hold, and for athiests it's even worse since they don't have a religion to know in the first place. So write about religions, write what you honestly think, and be very aware that you should avoid criticizing what you do not know. If you want to write about a religion, you should learn about it, and talk to it's followers, even if you are following it yourself.

If you're making a fictional religion, always think about how that religion was founded, how they are different from the original group they came out of, and how they solidified into the form they are in at the time of your story. With a Christian death cult, you could easily draw inspiration from the Cathars and other Gnostic groups which... Are sometimes Christian death cults. Oh yeah, they're really old. I think the biggest mistake you can do when making this group is by trying to portray it as a legitimate part of Christianity. When you have a religious extremist subgroup coming out of a major world religion in your story, you should always ensure that extremist group is in conflict with the religion it came out of, or you end up threatening to lump the main followers of a religion in with a group they would despise in real life.

Answer (score 1):

I would make sure that you're being practical and reasonable about your treatment of religion. People are highly offended by rash and unthinking stereotypes, but thoughtful, three-dimensional characters with conviction, and who act thoughtfully on that conviction, will be (1) engaging to read and (2) can raise meaningful and difficult questions about what happens when world views collide.

For example: Is it relevant to your story that your death cult is based on Christianity? Are there specific elements of Christian theology, doctrine, practice, or history that are meaningful here? If not, why are they Christian? Would the story work just as well with a "religious death cult" instead of a "Christian death cult"?

Whenever you invoke religion, ask yourself whether the religious identity matters and makes sense. If a character prays to "Jesus," does anything change if you replace that with "God?" If your cult crucifies someone, is that act consistent with how Christians view the crucifixion of Jesus? You might find out that the theme of your work is theism vs. atheism, rather than Christianity vs. atheism.

There are plenty of religious portrayals in media that are widely accepted. Religion shouldn't be shied away from, but realize that you're touching on something very personal and held very sincerely by a lot of people.

There are great works, for example, where two characters profess to be the same religion and hold the same beliefs, but act very differently (inviting the reader to understand why). There are great works where two characters of different religions and professing to hold different beliefs end up acting very similarly (again, asking the reader to interpret). There is every combination of the above.

Answer (score 1):

## Evil for evil religions often bring people out of the story.

Immersion is key when building a world, and having a religion which is based off a real world religion often has the effect of smashing that. The readers can feel that you're basically doing a rant against a real life group. Whether they agree with your rant or not, that makes them think of politics. There are several ways I've seen authors handle having Christianity in some form which can be evil.

## Have an example of good and evil Christianity.

The laundry files does this well. In several books they face the evil evangelist Raymond Schiller, who wants to resurrect his lord sleeping on another world who he sees as Jesus. Peter Wilson gives an example of proper Christianity, opposing the radical alien cultists of evil.

This lets you explore an evil Christianity without saying all Christians are evil.

## Have utterly insane and off the walls christianity which delves heavily into arcane symbology.

Evangelion and Bayonetta do this well. They don't really focus a lot on Christianity as is, but use the weird imagees of their angels and symbology from the more weird aspects of religion. Evangelion has lots of mystical Christian symbology which adds a vaguely mystic feeling to the show without referencing the moral stances of Christians.

This has the advantage of being weird, and not challenging the moral stance of religion, while letting you steal lots of symbology.

## Do a realistic religion which is actually well embedded in your world building.

Spellmonger does this well, with it emulating the rustic medieval religious feel with fairly weird gods like Ishi, goddess of love, whose tits are used as a swear word every few chapters. They follow some of the norms of Christianity economically and socially, but the actual religion is extremely non Christian, being focused on a polytheistic pantheon with clear differences.

This has the disadvantage that the religion won't be innately evil (since it's designed to fit in a real culture) but means you can set it in opposition to the protagonist at times.